# Complex impedance of a transformer

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism

I consider only an ideal transformer here (no leakage etc.).
Let L1 and L2 be the induction coefficients of the primary and secondary resp., and M be the mutual induction coefficient. Assume that the primary has n1 turns, and the secondary n2 turns.
Finally, assume that the secondary is connected to an (complex) impedance Z. What is the complex impedance of the primary ?
Put in another way, if we see the primary of the transformer whose secondary is wired to Z as a dipole, what is its complex input impedance?
I believe there should be such complex impedance, because all the components are passive and obey common law of induction.

After a lot of research on the web, I found only the following article that would provide approximatively an answer to this question; unfortunately, I found it unclear in many aspects:
[Couplage magnétique etc.](http://claude-gimenes.fr/fr/p/21/511/3838)
Since this question is theoretical, everything I have not specified can be introduced as a parameter, and the question can be reduced if needed.

EDIT: The terms "ideal transformer" are contradictory with the finite values of L1 and L2 given in the question. Indeed, according to several documents, an ideal transformer is one for which L1 and L2 tend to infinity, while the ratio of the wires remains constant.
For such ideal transformers, the answer has been given by user1582568. For non ideal transformers (L1 and L2 have finite values), 3 formulae were derived mathematically in my own answer below: the first one is the general case (but is still theoretical because it neglects the inner resistance of the self, and other type of noises). The second one is for 100% coupling (but finite L1 and L2), and the third one is the ideal transformer already given.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. I recommend at the very least you try drawing the problem. Then the arrow of the direction you're looking for the impedance

Comment: The keyword for this search is transformer or magnetically coupled equivalent circuit. Any circuit theory book will give you that kind of information.

Comment: Really? I am a 44 old man. I promise this is not a homework question.

Comment: Lancovici. I don't think this is a so common knowledge, but thank you anyway; I will read the source you've provided. The comments here sound like if I should remove the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impedance seen at the primary will be Z * (n1 / n2)^2 .

Comment: So, if the impedance is purely resistive (Z=R), the impedance seen at the primary is purely resistive ???

Comment: ... even given a value for M?

Comment: For M = 1 then yes. In your question you said "no leakage" so we cannot have M < 1

Comment: M is the coefficient of mutual induction. I don't understand what this has to do with leakage. Can you elaborate?

Comment: When the primary generates flux, ideally all this flux also passes through the secondary. The rate of change of flux induces an emf in the primary. If all flux passes through the secondary then the emf induced in the secondary will be the same number of volts per turn as in the primary. If I short the secondary, then any change of flux in the primary would have to generate emf in the secondary, which would result in equal and opposite flux, cancelling the change and preventing any emf in the primary. Therefore if M = 1, and I short the secondary, the primary has no self inductance. No leakage.

Comment: Leakage inductance is directly related to flux coupling, which is what gives rise to mutual inductance. (I need to get better at using less words).

Comment: I can feel this if the secondary is shorted (+1 for your answer), but if it is connected to a pure resistance, I still find counter intuitive that the primary behaves like a resistor as you said in your answer.

Comment: OK, in a real transformer there will be effects because M<>1, the winding inductances are finite, the winding have resistance, the code magnetics are not perfectly linear. But consider a 1:1 transformer loaded with 100R. If I apply 1V to the primary I get 1V on the secondary. 10mA flows in the secondary and 10mA flows in the primary initially. In order to maintain the 1V emf, core flux has to rise at a steady rate, this requires a small increasing current in the primary, so the 10mA goes up over time in a linear ramp. Eventually the core saturates and the voltage collapses.

Comment: Why doesn't your answer account for inductance L1 (the magnetization inductance) - it is present all the time and it will be in parallel with the secondary impedance transferred to the primary. This answer is too simplistic.

Comment: @ Andyaka, my previous comment explains the effect of the primary inductance. My original answer concentrated on the conceptual aspect. A close-to-ideal transformer has inductance approaching infinity with negligible effect. Of course you are right, the inductance is there, along with the other aspects of a real transformer, and the actual impedance is rather complex (and in fact non linear if the transformer has a core), but these additional terms are specific to the particular design and hopefully small  for the intended application. Your point is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

> I consider only an ideal transformer here (no leakage etc.).

An ideal transformer with no leakage means unequivocally the coupling is 100%. This means that the impedance of the secondary is "transported" to the primary side by the turns ratio squared.

> What is the complex impedance of the primary ?

If the primary has infinite impedance (a true power transformer/converter in the theoretical sense), then the impedance looking into that primary is as stated above but, the primary has a magnetization inductance totally defined in the question as L1: -

> Let L1 and L2 be the induction coefficients of the primary and
>   secondary resp.

Therefore the input impedance into the "L1" primary is the answer above but in parallel with the inductance L1.

L2 plays no part in the answer because L2 isn't "felt" by L1 when it is open circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Well the key words "magnetically coupled equivalent circuit" of Lancovici has lead me to some hints. I found in a document (and this comes in fact from the very definitions) that we have the system

u1 = L1 d i1/dt + j w M d i2/dt

u2 = M d i1/dt + L2 d i2/dt

In the frequency domain, this gives

u1 = j w  L1 i1 + j w M i2

u2 = j w M i1 + j w L2 i2

Now, hoping my derivation is correct, we have 
u2 = Z i2 ; substituting this value into the second equation, and eliminating i2 between the two equations, we get

u1 = ( j w L1 + (w^2 M^2)/(Z + j w L2) ) i1, hence the apparent impedance (first formula in the general case).

In the case where the coefficient of coupling k = M/(L1L2)^(1/2) is close (or equal) to 1, then reporting into the above equation leads to

u1 = ( j w L1 Z / (Z + j w L2) ) i1, hence the impedance of the primary in this case (second formula for 100% coupling).

Finally, in the so called case of an "ideal transformer" were L1 and L2 are very large while the ratio L2/L1 = a^2 remains constant (a can be shown to be the ratio of the number of wires in the primary and the secondary), then the previous formula reduces to

u1 = L1/L2 Z i1 = Z/a^2 i1. This coincides with the answer of user1582568 (third formula).

Comment: Why doesn't your answer account for inductance L1 (the magnetization inductance) - it is present all the time and it will be in parallel with the secondary impedance transferred to the primary. This answer is too simplistic. L1 is always present at the primary and represents the impedance looking into the primary when the secondary is unloaded.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks Andy aka. Actually, L1 is present in the formulae above. I did my best to give a mathematically justified answer, that also coincides, in the special case of the ideal transformer, with the answer of user1582568. But I would be extremely happy to see a more correct mathematical derivation if you can write it in another answer in this thread (in that case I will remove (or edit) my own answer). Alternatively, you could point out precisely how to correct the previous derivation.

Comment: Notice also that I have explicitly stated that the last formula of my answer (that does not account for inductance L1) is only valid as an approximation whenever the inductances L1 and L2 are very large (ideal transformers) and M=1.  The other formulae does account for L1.

Comment: My answer is already given and states that L1 is in parallel with the transformed impedance on the secondary.

Comment: Andy aka. 1) This is not what you wrote at the end of your answer, so you may consider editing your answer in order for it to reflect more precisely you thoughts. 2) If I understand your present answer, you are saying that the impedance seen at the primary is jwL1 in parallel with (Z - jwL2), or maybe (Z+jwL2) or maybe Z*n1^2/n2^2 (this would have been clear if you had written down the formula). In any of these cases, this does not coincide with the formula that were mathematically derived from the axioms.

Comment: So unless you can point out where this derivation is incorrect, or eventually give another derivation or a source, I think it is fair and reasonable to continue to believe that it is the correct answer (sorry if I disagree with you for the moment, I may change my mind of course). Note: I have added and edit to my question that may explain the cause of the flaw.